# QR decomposition for finding eigenvectors of non symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was trying to understand if QR decomposition algorithm can be used to calculate the eigenvector of a non symmetric square invertible real matrix (by multiplicaton of the Q's).